# How to Package/Publish SQL databases with ASP.NET MVC 2 Website?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy, database-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET MVC 2 Website for the first time on a local IIS 7 server, which is configured and running. I've made successful deployments using the Web Deploy option without the databases (so the site isn't fully working yet). Most of the deployment settings are pretty intuitive, however, I have problems with the Package/Publish SQL -tab in the project settings. Here's how it looks like with the errors I'm getting (click for bigger view).

[image]

It asks for Connection String, but I have no idea what to put there. It also gives a weird error about another process using a schema file.

Any pointers are welcome. I'm looking for the easiest way to just get it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the databases running by unchecking the "Exclude files from the App Data folder" in Package/Publish Web tab. It then simply copies the database files.