# Recreate database from RedGate checked-in scripts

Tags: sql-server, powershell, redgate

We've got a SQL Server instance with some 15-20 databases, which we check in TFS with the help of RedGate. I'm working on a script to be able to replicate the instance (so a developer could run a local instance when needed, for example) with the help of these scripts. What I'm worried about is the dependencies between these scripts.

In TFS, RedGate has created these folders with `.sql` files for each database:

```
Functions
Security
Stored Procedures
Tables
Triggers
Types
Views
```

I did a quick test with Powershell, just looping over these folders to execute the sql, but I think that might not always work. Is there a strict ordering which I can follow? Or is there some simpler way to do this? To clarify, I want to be able to start with an completly empty SQL Server instance, and end up with a fully configured one according to what is in the TFS (without data, but that is ok). Using Powershell is not a requirement, so if it is simpler to do some other way, that is preferrable.

Comment: No idea if it would be a good fit for your situation or not, but just to include it, the Web Deploy (aka 'msdeploy') framework includes support for publishing databases as well.

Comment: here's a related SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471580/how-to-package-publish-sql-databases-with-asp-net-mvc-2-website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using RedGate they have a ton of articles on how to move changes from source control to database. Here's one which describes moving database code from TFS using sqcompare command-line:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168595/Continuous-Integration-for-Database-Development

If you compare to any empty database it will create the script you are looking for.

Comment: Empty compare seems like it will work. I can write a PS script which creates the databases and the populates them using sqlcompare. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to deploy the database from scripts folders would be to use Red Gate SQL Compare. If you run the .sql files using PowerShell, the objects may not be created in the right order. Even if you run them in an order that makes sense (functions, then tables, then views...), you still may have dependency issues.

SQL Compare reads all of the scripts and uses them to construct a "virtual" database in memory, then it calculates a dependency matrix for it so when the deployment script is created, things are done in the correct order. That will prevent SQL Server from throwing dependency-related errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio with the database option it includes a Schema Compare that will allow you to compare what is in the database project in TFS to the local instance. It will create a script for you to have those objects created in the local instance. I have not tried doing this for a complete instance.

You might have to at most create the databases in the local instance and then let Visual Studio see that the tables and other objects are not there.

You could also just take the last backup of each database and let the developer restore them to their local instance. However this can vary on each environment depending on security policy and what type of data is in the database.

I tend to just use PowerShell to build the scripts for me. I have more control over what is scripted out when so when I rerun the scripts on the local instance I can do it in the order it needs to be done in. May take a little more time but I get better functioning scripts for me to work with, and PS is just my preference. There are some good scripts already written in the SQL Community that can help you on this. [Jen McCown](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/about/) did a blog post of all the post her husband has written for doing just this, [right here](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/05/script-sql-objects-with-powershell/).

Answer (score 0):

I've blogged about how to build a database from a set of .sql files using the SQL Compare command line.

http://geekswithblogs.net/SQLDev/archive/2012/04/16/how-to-build-a-database-from-source-control.aspx

The post is more from the point of view of setting up continuous integration, but the principles are the same.